# What do I do if someone posts an answer I had as a comment?

Tags: support, answers, comments

[This](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7181/is-it-rude-to-answer-a-question-that-has-been-solved-in-comments) just happened [here](https://superuser.com/questions/505389/is-there-a-way-to-create-synchronization-profiles-for-google-chrome). I posted a possible solution as a comment (not being sure if it would work for the asker), and while I was waiting for a reply, [krowe](https://superuser.com/users/145045/krowe) posted basically what I had as an answer. It is somewhat more specific than my comments, but I was there first. To top it off, the question has an active bounty on it. What should be done here?

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6822/comments-to-a-question-that-should-be-answers

Comment: @OliverSalzburg _Should_ my comment be an answer? I posted it as a comment because I wasn't sure. I do keep Stack Exchange open, and watch my notifications; if the asker had replied saying “Yes, this answers my question, you may post it as an answer”, I definitely would have…but as of now, the asker hasn't even been on the site in two days.

Comment: I don't really see how the answer just copies your comment. Yes, both mention use of multiple profiles, but that's where the similarities end. In fact, I'm not sure krowe even saw your comment, given he mentions *"the bookmarks won't be synced across profiles"*, instead suggesting use of a service like Xmarks (which seems to be quite different from what you suggest).

Comment: @DanielBeck Something like Xmarks on both profiles to “bridge” them together is exactly what I meant.

Comment: You suggested a local process requiring multiple browser instances on a specific machine in only the broadest strokes. If krowe was even aware of your comment, then the answer *significantly* improved upon your suggestion (at least in terms of user-friendliness). While I don't doubt that you could answer the question, you didn't (yet — I'd consider your approach to be significantly different from krowe's as to not think it's a duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see different, You prodded for more information, I don't know of anything stopping you from writing your own answer still.

Ok so now it might be a bit duplicate :-(  But you could put your own thoughts, your own ideas in, expand on what is said, put in pictures.
there is nothing stopping you from creating a "better" answer still.  being a bounty question it could still be worth it to you.

For the first part, somebody stole my answer off the comments, this ends up assuming that hundreds of people of the billions on this planet could not have answered the question, one of them did. It is neither accepted yet, nor will it be going away for quite some time, so any good answer you have can still gain some rep number things.
Or you could just expand and paraphrase on it, and anyone Finding it will have reinforced information from (mabey) a different communications style.

More is better, When it doesnt work, you can always Delete your answer later.  I say go for it, you have nothing to lose.

Confusion say: He who make his own way, find a way to make it.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want someone to "steal" your solution, you should post an answer.

If you simply can't answer the question because the author didn't provide enough details, then it's a good idea to use comments to confirm with the author if a certain approach would help solve the issue. In this case it is clear that what you suggest *could* solve the issue. So you could have posted an answer explaining the approach.

You can't "reserve" a solution to a question by posting a short comment. Other people might come up with the identical solution as well.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll remember this in case there's a next time.

Comment: `(+1)` Comments should be used only for clarification of the post (question or answer).  If there's an answer, then it should be posted as such, even if you're not %100 sure it's going to work.